# Dynamic Insert -- ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to implement a simple procedure that calculates the proportion of distinct values of a given field and stores the result in an auxiliary table.

```
  CREATE TABLE TEST_DATA_QTY_AND
  (

  TABLE_ID VARCHAR2(30),
  FLD_ID VARCHAR2(30),
  MEASURE NUMBER(1, 2),
  DATA_T DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
  NOTES VARCHAR2(255)

  );


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DATA_QTY_AND(pTable IN VARCHAR2, pField IN VARCHAR2)

 IS


v_sql varchar2(2000);


v_sql := 'INSERT INTO TEST_DATA_QTY_AND (TABLE_ID, FLD_ID, MEASURE)'||
         'VALUES('||
         pTable||', '||pField||', ('||
         'SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN '||pField||' <> 0 THEN 1 END) /COUNT(*) FROM'||
         pTable||'));';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(v_sql);

COMMIT;

   EXCEPTION
   ...
   END;
```

However, I keep getting ERROR- ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to put single quotes around your literal string values, and the single quotes being used to contain the dynamic SQL string don't count.  We can try using two single quotes to represent a single literal single quote:

```
v_sql := 'INSERT INTO TEST_DATA_QTY_AND (TABLE_ID, FLD_ID, MEASURE) ' ||
         'VALUES(' ||
         '''' || pTable || ''', ''' || pField || ''', (' ||
         'SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ' || pField || ' <> 0 THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) FROM ' ||
         pTable || '))';
```

Note that in the subquery you are comparing `pField`, a text variable, against `0`, without quotes, i.e. an integer.  This doesn't make sense, so in the above snippet I compare against `'0'` instead of a number.

Comment: pField refers to a numeric field of pTable

Comment: Well, your function signature shows that `pField` is `VARCHAR2`, not a number.  So, my answer doesn't change unless your function also changes.

Comment: pField is VARCHAR2 as it refers to the name (and not the type) of a given column of pTable. The referenced field is numeric; hence the comparison with 0.

Answer (score 2):

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected.

Your string looks like this:

```
FROM'||
pTable||'));';
```

There is no space after the literal `FROM` so the assembled code will concatenated the table name parameter with the FROM to make a string like:

```
SEELCT COLUMN_1 FROMTABLE_23
```

Hence the error.

Dynamic SQL is hard because it turns compilation errors into runtime errors. You will save yourself a lot of grief if you put in some debug. A simple `dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);` would have allowed you to see the assembled code: you would probably have spotted your bloomer immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is not very clear, I am trying to clarify what I understood (by stretching my imagination) of it with following example / further description

Let us say you have two main tables

```
create table tbl_1(
    id          int not null primary_key,
    value_1     int 
);
create table tbl_2(
    id          int not null primary_key,
    value_2     int 
);
```

In case you pass tbl_1, value_1 as parameters to your procedure, your insert SQL should be

```
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA_QTY_AND (TABLE_ID, FLD_ID, MEASURE) values ('tbl_1', 'value_1', (select sum(case when value_1 <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) from tbl_1))
```

When you pass tbl_2, value_2 as parameters to your procedure, your insert SQL should be

```
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA_QTY_AND (TABLE_ID, FLD_ID, MEASURE) values ('tbl_2', 'value_2', (select sum(case when value_2 <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) from tbl_2))
```

If this understanding is correct then following should work

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DATA_QTY_AND(pTable IN VARCHAR2, pField IN VARCHAR2)
IS
  v_sql varchar2(2000);
BEGIN

  v_sql :=  utl_lms.format_message(
        'INSERT INTO TEST_DATA_QTY_AND (TABLE_ID, FLD_ID, MEASURE) VALUES('''%s''', '''%s''', '
      ||'(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN %s <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/ COUNT(*) FROM %s))',  
      pTable, pField, pField, pTable);  

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(v_sql);
END;
```

**Note** I have left transaction and exception handling for you as an exercise. Also note, at the time of writing this, I don't have access to Oracle DB, hence couldn't create / compile to weed out any error / problem. You should take a stab at fixing problems (if any). In case you are unable to, leave a comment, I shall do so when I have access to a DB instance.

HOWEVER, all these only when my expansion of your problem is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `execute immediate` with variables after `using` keyword

```
create or replace procedure data_qty_and ( pTable varchar2, pField varchar2 ) is
 v_sql varchar2(2000);
begin
  v_sql := 'insert into test_data_qty_and( table_id, fld_id, measure  )
            select :1, :2, sum(case when :2 <> 0 then 1 end ) /count(*) from '||pTable;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
  execute immediate v_sql using pTable, pField, pField;

  commit;
 exception when others then dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
end;
```

using bind variables is always far better than string concatenation,  which might be vulnerable to injection attacks , in a code block.